# How to use for loop in column dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, for-loop

I have a big csv file with information about 911 calls. The describtion of the calls are long string:

```
2015-12-10 @ 14:39:21-Station:STA27;

OLD YORK RD & VALLEY RD; CHELTENHAM; 2015-12-10 @ 17:12:47;
```

I wan't to filter out the Rows without Station in it. And del the part what's standing for station.

I have a script but I'm not sure how to use it. Can anyone help me?

The script:

```
for i in range(len(station)):
    if x[0] != 'S':
       x = x[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to extract a group from the string.

```
    import re
    e = re.compile("(Station\s*:*\s*\w*;+)")
    r = e.search("REINDEER CT & DEAD END; NEW HANOVER; Station 332; 2015-12-10 @ 17:10:52;").group(1)
    print(r)
    //prints Station 332;
```